# Multiple layouts on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I have the application layout and i'm trying create other layout like a dashboard.  i have doubt about how create the controller and the requires in js. 
The controller will be just like the application? and when i add the layout the console ask me to add on pre-compile the css and js. this means that the css and js will be pre-loaded in my application ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're asking. Can you clarify your intentions by explaining your use-case and provide some code?
I mean no offense by this, but it sounds like you struggle with english enough that it's hard to understand your meaning. It might be good if you grab someone who is a bit more knowledgeable in the language.

Comment: The rails guide on layouts is probably a good place to start: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the base controller like it**

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout: 'my_application'

    **some methods at here**

end
```

**and create**

> app/views/layouts/my_application.html.erb

**then your other controllers which you want use my_application.html.erb
as layout you can inherit BaseController**

like

```
class HomeController < BaseController
  **some methods at here**
end
```

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: My doubt was in how create de controller in a second layout. and the
extend with BaseController make it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for example you created a layout named **mylayout.html.erb**, in this layout, you need to mention like this:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And in controller, we just add:

```
layout "mylayout"
```